# Assign a Name to each Iteration

Tags: matlab, loops

In Matlab, I'm trying to assign a name for each iteration in a for loop. Let's take the fundamental for loop:

```
for i = 1:3
x = i^2
end
```

And the the output is:

```
x = 1;
x = 4;
x = 9;
```

What I want to do is assign the x's as `x(1)`, `x(2)`, and `x(3)`. So what I'm trying to achieve is to have a for loop output as:

```
x(1) = 1;
x(2) = 4;
x(3) = 9;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the for loop you showed, the scalar value x gets updated on every iteration. What you can do instead is store the values of the iteration in a vector.

For instance:

```
for i = 1:3
  x(i) = i^2;
end
```

x is a vector and x(i) holds the ith iteration.

Comment: +1 but you should also add the idiomatic Matlab way to do this: i = 1:3; x = i.^2; as an alternative at the end.